# MongoDb aggregate use $sortByCount inside a $group

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation

I am trying to aggregate data using mongoDb to gather data per user.  I have the following query:

```
DB.collection.aggregate([
    { "$facet": {
        "instructions": [
                { $match: { company: ref } },
                { $group: {
                    _id : '$user._id',
                    firstName: { $first: "$user.firstName"},
                    lastName: { $last: "$user.lastName"},
                    total: { $sum: 1 },
                    completed: { $sum: { 
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$completed.value", true ] }, 
                            1, 0
                        ]}
                    },
                    mostPopularProduct: {
                        $sortByCount: "$productType"  
                    },
                    mostPopularType: {
                        $sortByCount: "$instructionType"  
                    }
                }},
            ]
        }},
        { "$project": {
            "perClient": { "instructions": "$instructions"  }
        }}
    }}
])
```

I am trying to get the `mostPopularProduct` (and `mostPopularInstruction`) in my collection from a string field inside all documents that matches the `$match`.  Basically the product that appears most across all documents.  There are a couple of more calculations being done inside the group.

Currently, I am getting the following error: `"unknown group operator '$sortByCount'"`.  Now I know it is because it is being used inside the group, which it cannot.  But I am unsure how to achieve the desired result. I tried using `$sum`, but I did not achieve what I wanted.  I don't know if I used it incorrectly.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

Okay, so I might have been a bit vague about what I want.  Let me clarify a bit.

I have used `$sortByCount` before, like this:

```
"mostPopularProduct": [
    { $match: { company: ref } },
    { $sortByCount: "$productType"}
],
```

The result I got was:

```
"mostPopularProduct": [
    {
        "_id": "car",
        "count": 14
    }, {
        "_id": "house",
        "count": 2
    }
]
```

Now, I want to do the exact same thing, but I want it inside of my group,  So basically I want to get the following result:

```
"perClient": {
    "instructions": [
        {
            "_id": "5fd3db7427e9bc610e4daeaa",
            "firstName": "firstName",
            "lastName": "lastName",
            "total": 8,
            "completed": 1,
            // NOW HERE ARE THE FIELDS I WANT
            "mostPopularProduct": [
                {
                    "_id": "car",
                    "count": 3
                }
            ]
        }, // all other clients follow
    ]
}
```

This is the required result I am trying to achieve with the $sortByCount, inside of a $group.

Here is an example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/XolUjfDCpxn

Comment: *how to achieve the desired result* => hard to predict your desired result, it would helpful if you add some sample document and expected result in your question.

Comment: Thanks @turivishal, I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Documents:

```
[
  { userId: 1, productType: "car" },
  { userId: 1, productType: "car" },
  { userId: 1, productType: "bus" },
  { userId: 1, productType: "bus" },
  { userId: 2, productType: "bus" },
  { userId: 2, productType: "bus" }
]
```

- `$group` by `userId` and `productType` and count the sum
- `$group` by only `userId` and prepare the array of `productType` and count

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "instructions": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              userId: "$userId",
              productType: "$productType"
            },
            productTypeCount: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id.userId",
            mostPopularProduct: {
              $push: {
                _id: "$_id.productType",
                count: "$productTypeCount"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/myaag7gq7eJ)

Comment: wont that separate the new field from the previous or existing fields?

Comment: i am not getting you exactly, just post your actual document.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: can you confirm this https://mongoplayground.net/p/MKm5IWg1-yS

Comment: Thanks @turivishal, that looks perfect.  It just confuses me that product type is inside the group.

Comment: could you please assist again?  I figured I'd ask you instead of posting again.  If you look at your example, I am trying to get the 'mostPopularInstructionType", the same way you got the 'mostPopularProduct'.

Comment: its really hard to do in a single query. i will try if its possible.